# How to parse nested array where the inner array needs a variable of the outer array

Tags: ansible

when running an ansible task, a json array is passed as extra variables like this:

```
ansible-playbook --extra-vars '{"brands":["vw","bmw"], "vw":["golf","tiguan"],"bmw":["5 series","7 series"]}'
```

how to parse such a json extra variable in ansible?

```
-name: something
 debug: msg=item
 with_items: {{brands}}
```

then I need to access the sub-brands of each brand, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can access a variable name through the results of another variable. An alternative is to define a dictionary variable, in a file as so:

```
brands:
- name: vw
  makes:
    - golf
    - tiguan
- name: bmw
  makes:
    - 5series
    - 7series
```

Then in ansible you can get all the makes by calling:

```
- name: Print car make
  debug: msg="{{item.1}}"
  with_subelements:
    - brands
    - makes
```